# Submit button returns to index page instead of sending data

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

Here is the link for the website - http://zigzagadvertising.com.ph/aleemguiapal/page/2/

I have a problem regarding my forms in wordpress. Whenever i click on the submit button it returns to the index page instead of sending the data into an email address

**This is my PHP code which i placed on top of the Header.php. This code is placed before the  tag**

```
<?php 
$error=false;
$sent=false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(empty($_POST['firstname']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
$error = true;
} else {

 $to = "clestcruz@gmail.com";

 $name = trim($_POST['firstname']);
 $email = trim($_POST['email']);
 $comments = trim($_POST['message']);

 $subject = "Contact Form";

 $messages = "Name: $firstname \r\n Email: $email \r\n Comments: $message";
 $headers = "From:" . $name;
 $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers);

 if($mailsent){
     $sent= true;
}
}
}
?>
```

**And this is my custom page(Contact Page)**

```
<!--CONTACT-->
<div  class="container">
<div  class="eleven columns contact">
     <div id="contact-container" class="eleven columns alpha omega contact">
         <h2>contact us</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non lacus vel nulla molestie cursus quis a urna. Donec sodales venenatis consequat. Sed tristique elit nec diam rhoncus adipiscing</p>
     </div>

     <div id="note-container" class="eleven columns alpha omega note">
         <p>All fields marked with an asterisk(<span class="asterisk">*</span>) are required</p>
     </div>

     <div class="contactform">
     <form id="register-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">


     <?php if($error == true) { ?>
     <p class="error"> There are some misisng fields.</p>
     <?php } if($sent == true) { ?>
     <p class="sent">Thank you for sending your message</p><?php } ?>


         <div class="four columns alpha contact-form">

         <label>prefix</label>
         <input type="text"  />
         <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>first name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
         <label><span class="asterisk"></span>middle name</label>
         <input type="text" name="middlename"/>
         <label><span class="asterisk"></span>last name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
         <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>email address</label>
         <input type="text" name="email"/>

        </div>

        <div class="four columns contact-form">

         <label>phone</label>
         <input type="text" />
         <label>street</label>
         <input type="text" />
         <label><span class="asterisk"></span>zip</label>
         <input type="text" name="zip" />
         <label><span class="asterisk"></span>city</label>
         <input type="text" name="city" />


        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="eleven columns contact-form alpha omega">

        <label><span class="asterisk"></span>subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject"/>
        <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>message</label>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>


        <input class="contact-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        <input class="contact-button" type="reset" value="reset" />

        </div>

     </form>
     </div>

<div class="four columns">
</div>

</div>



 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>   


<?php get_footer(); ?>



</body>
</html>
```

I tried making a contact page and uploaded it into a free hosting site and it seem to be working properly. I even got the data or values in the forms. Not sure if the reason why my forms is not working properly is because of wordpress itself.

Comment: what is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: Change the action to "". I believe that will do it.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean? I'm sorry if do not know the answers to that also since i just followed a tutorial and not yet familiar with PHP yet.

Comment: @user602525 what do you mean by hardcoding it?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have the form submit to the current page then set your method to an empty string:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

Personally, I'd separate out that logic form your `header.php` into a separate file for cleaner code organization. In the separate file you could use

```
header('location: http://whatever.com/contact');
```

to redirect after you're done processing form data.

Comment: Actually the data is supposed to be sent to a specific email address.

Comment: When you said separating the logic. Do you mean like linking it just like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="url" />

Comment: I mean, the `header.php` file is really only supposed to handle the header of every page. However, not every page load is going to need to  process form data. So, while it works it sort of gets in the way of things. Not to mention if you have another form and put it in your `header.php` now that's even more code that isn't always used but sit there. I'm looking at this from a MVC standpoint where you separate doing things from displaying things.

Comment: Yes i get your point. At the moment working on fixing this problem and then will separate the back-end codes after. Is separating the logic easy. I'm working on a wordpress theme at the moment

Comment: It's a little tougher with WP because WP was not conceived with MVC in mind but it's not terribly hard either. Mostly it just involves forethought. The way I look at it is, I'm lazy. I want to make my life as easy as possible. So, I try to reduce the amount of thinking I have to do. A year from now if you look at your code will it instantly make sense or will you have to relearn it? If you think you'll have to relearn you might want to consider refactoring things to make it easier down the line.

Comment: Well i'm a front-end developer with a little bit of back-end. So all of this back-end coding is still new to me. I managed to develop or code this WP theme from scratch thanks to google and also amazing support from stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] refers to the filename of the currently executing script. In this case the currently executing script is your custom page (contact page). If that is not the same file as the header.php you mention, then the form is not submitting where you want it to.

I'd recommend just specifying the header.php explicitly as the form target if that is where you want the data to submit, and then redirecting to where you want to go after the form is submitted successfully.

Comment: Hello adam, the objective here is to pass the data to to the email address. I have added the link to the website in my problem

Comment: The "action" attribute of your form is being set to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] which is a PHP variable that sets it to the filename of the currently executing script. In the case of the website you provided it actually translates to<form id="register-form" action="/aleemguiapal/index.php" method="post">. If you want it to point to another file, you should specify that instead. For example <form id="register-form" action="/aleemguiapal/header.php" method="post">.

Comment: I guess it's different in wordpress hmm. Let me see if i can work this out. PHP is something new to me.